What are sun dried tomato HALVES?
I know what sun dried tomatoes are and am looking to purchase some.  However I notice a lot of sun dried tomato products say ‘halves’.  Does this simply mean the tomato was cut in half then dried so you are getting the whole fruit complete with seeds etc but in half pieces or something else?
Thanks

Does -1 mean I asked a stupid question?!!

I can't speak for the downvoter, but the criteria for downvoting includes a lack of research effort. It does seem to me you could have answered your own question here and that may be the reason.

Yes.  Tomato...cut in half...then dried...then packaged.

Dried tomatoes virtually always contain "seeds, etc." - halves (normally from smaller tomatoes for efficient processing - drying half of a large tomato takes far too long) happen to be easier to deal with because they can be set on the skin side, which does not stick to the rack or screen as much as the face of a cut slice will. Most of the heirloom "drying" tomatoes are fairly small, I assume for this reason.
I generally don't attempt to dry large tomatoes, and if faced with some "medium" sized ones I will try to cut them in sections that can be set on the skin side (without falling over) since non-skin slices are such a pain to get off the rack when dry.

having also means that they don't have intact skin protecting them from drying out.  I've never tried drying my own tomatoes but for peppers it dramatically reduces the time to dry and reduces the chance of it going moldy

Has never even occurred to me to try and dry them whole. I guess I have seen references to folks in nice dry climates pulling up the whole plant and drying tomatoes on the plant, whole, but that won't work where I live.

I don't even know if you can dry whole tomatoes successfully.  There are some varieties that will last long on the vine, and get smoked to preserve them (possibly to help disinfect the outside?)
